# How to remove all html in post content and only trim text in php?

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

Currently i am doing a CMS in laravel currently i am trying to get all the html removed from posts.

```
{!! str_limit($post->content, 230) !!}
```

The problem i am getting is that it gets html as well.
Next i tried Strip_tags function, it didn't display the html.

```
{!! strip_tags(str_limit($post->content, 230)) !!}
```

But it didn't displayed anything either..it worked but it counted the html tags as well. I need to just ignore html tags.

Is there any way or function to ignore all the html tags inside the post content and just get the text out of post content?

Thanks 
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You're doing it backwards. First strip tags, _then_ limit the text.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank you so much it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple use strip_tags with substr

```
    <?php echo substr(strip_tags($post->content,0,110)) . "..."; ?>
```

Comment: Think your missing a )

Comment: Hmm, that's why i was getting php error!
Thank you, problem solved, i was using it in opposite order

Comment: @SarojSardar Please upvote my answer if this answer is helpful for you